# Performance / Practice PHP & Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

So I'm working on this project and I'm not sure which is the better practice and if it does affect performance

So i have 2 database tables

**1: Students** This table has **id , Name , Teacher_id , date**

**2: Teachers** This table has **id , Name , date**

My goal here is to display all students and get the name of the teachers. Here are both methods that I have.

**Method 1**

Call from my Model

```
public static function GetTeacher($id){
   return Teacher::where('id',$id)->first();
}
```

And in my controller

```
Teacher::GetTeacher($student->teacher_id)->name;
```

**Method 2**

Do everything in the model and do a **left joint** on both tables?

So the main question is which method is better, or is there a better way of doing this. If i can get an article to read on it would be nice.

Thanks.

Comment: have you used eloquent model relation? your relation seems teacher_has_many_student? did you write this one to many relation in the model?

Comment: @MuhaimenulIslam No, i'm using just eloquent with SLIM3 framework not using laravel , so I haven't imported the relations package